# What is the difference between 非親告罪 and 親告罪?

Tags: meaning, kanji, prefixes

**非親告罪【ひしんこくざい】　vs　親告罪【しんこくざい】**

To my understanding **親告罪** means: A type of crime which requires a formal complaint from the victim in order to prosecute.

**非【ひ】** means: a mistake, negative, injustice, non, un, etc...

So is the first word like a double negative? In other words like not a crime?  A conversation of these two words happened during a talk recently and I didn't quite fully understand.  Any in-depth explanation would be great!

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1893/7810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

非親告罪 doesn't mean decriminalization. It means non-親告罪、that is to say, investigative organization can prosecute the accused without a requirement for a formal complaint from the victim in order to prosecute.

Comment: So in this case it could be seen as *non*? like *non*親告罪 的な感じ？

Comment: It seems so. http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e9%9d%9e

Answer (score 1):

When you see the Kanji 非 used before another word, you should always suspect it is used as a prefix in order to make it opposite of the word without 非.

For example,

> [常識]{じょうしき}: common sense vs 非常識: lack of common sense, or absurdity.
>
> [紳士的]{しんしてき}: gentlemanly vs 非紳士的: ungentlemanly
>
> [会員]{かいいん}: a member vs 非会員: a non-member

Therefore, 非親告罪 means the opposite of 親告罪, in other words, 非親告罪 is the crime that is not 親告罪 in the same way as 会員 means a member and 非会員 means someone who is not a member.

There are other suffixes that have similar functions to 非 such as 不, 未 and so on. They have different usages and have to be learned on a case by case basis.